# нормально когда Order принадлежит к user_id и customer_id, product_id?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

У users может быть много orders. А orders чтобы собирался из нескольких таблиц (данные клиента в customers, данные продукта в products)

К примеру поля orders:

```php
$table->id();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('customer_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');

$table->timestamps();
```

К примеру поля users:

```php
$table->id();
$table->string('name');
$table->string('phone');
$table->string('email');
$table->timestamps();
```

К примеру поля customers:

```php
$table->id();
$table->string('name');
$table->string('phone');
$table->timestamps();
```

К примеру поля products:

```php
$table->id();
$table->string('name');
$table->string('price');
$table->timestamps();
```

Пользователь сайта (user) добавляет новый заказ, вводит данные клиента и что он заказал.

Так вот чтобы данные клиента сохранились в таблицу customers, а данные что он заказал в таблицу products к примеру, а в таблицу orders записались

```php
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('customer_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
```

Или предложите ваш вариант

Comment: У заказа может быть несколько товаров, так что лучше создать смежную таблицу orders_products с order_id, product_id в ней.

Comment: orders_products сделать многие ко многим, а вот остальные поля что в orders оставить как тесть?

Comment: Да, оставьте id, user_id и customer_id

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov
спасибо